# Modification of CSS while the id is different on the xhtml page. (jsf page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsf, xhtml

Scenario : 
I have an A.xhtml page which on button click opens another page : B.xhtml. On page A i have an option which presents the layout in either a list view or a block view. When chosing the list view the css is working perfectly for page B while it is being pop up. But when we change the option to Block View on page A, the css on Page B is incorrect.

Solutions : (if there is a better solution please precise thanks)

1. Change the css to a new one using javascript but the issue is that am not able to capture the id used for the grid/list view.
2. Use of a conditional css but i don't know how to apply it in this context.

Thank you for your help in advanced.

Comment: On button click send this object and get formId from it.

Comment: Can you please details yours answer i am a bit novice it in?

Comment: While switching to another xhtml you can check which type is selected and enforce css according to it

Comment: How exactly are you switching between list view and block view in the B page? Can you show some code?